# Wordpress Custom Post Type adding tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a Wordpress site I have created some custom Post Types all work fine create the post etc.

What I need however is custom taxonomies with some of the custom Post Types, I have set this up and when adding different tags to the taxonomy it works however, when creating a post for a custom post type in the taxonomy block clicking add tag it just does a anchor link to #Member news Category-add

Nothing else happens, it's not a big bug but I would however, like to fix this so it is correct for the time I go live

Is this a known bug? or is there something I have probably missed when creating the custom post type?

```
 register_post_type('member_news', array(   'label' => 'Member News','description' => 'News content submitted by members of RRUKA.','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member-news'),'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Member News',
  'singular_name' => 'Member News',
  'menu_name' => 'Member News',
  'add_new' => 'Add Member News',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Member News',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Member News',
  'new_item' => 'New Member News',
  'view' => 'View Member News',
  'view_item' => 'View Member News',
  'search_items' => 'Search Member News',
  'not_found' => 'No Member News Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Member News Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Member News',
),) );
```

Any information on this would be very welcome

Comment: Can you post your code related to creating the custom post type in question.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript error on the 'Add New' page?

Comment: no I have no JavaScript errors in my console

Comment: and Jrod I have posted my code thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to  add this parameter in your array
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') ,

```
register_post_type('member_news', array(   'label' => 'Member News','description' => 'News content submitted by members of RRUKA.','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member-news'),'query_var' => true,'has_archive' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'menu_position' => 5,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),
'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') , 
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Member News',
  'singular_name' => 'Member News',
  'menu_name' => 'Member News',
  'add_new' => 'Add Member News',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Member News',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Member News',
  'new_item' => 'New Member News',
  'view' => 'View Member News',
  'view_item' => 'View Member News',
  'search_items' => 'Search Member News',
  'not_found' => 'No Member News Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Member News Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Member News',
),) );
```